# Array empty even after a loop

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to fill an array with some registers from a database. However, even after retrieving said registers and place them into the array, after the loop the array stays empty

```
const userParties = [];

userFollowing.forEach(element => {
  // Here's when I gather the information that I need
  dispatchGetUserEvents(element.user, response => {
    userParties.push(response);
    console.log(userParties); // Here the array is full of elements, like it's supposed to be
  });
});

console.log(userParties); // However, here 'userParties' return '[]'
this.setState({ followUsersEvents: userParties });
this.setState({ userImage: userImg });
```

I tried to update the state array on the loop, but I had no luck there either.
'userParties' is not a state array btw.

Comment: 99% that dispatchGetUserEvents is async function so response will come later, but you try to output userParties while you didn't get result from it, so second console.log(userParties) will execute first and then will be executed console.log from response

Comment: Mussing definition of `dispatchGetUserEvents`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const userParties = [];

userFollowing.forEach(element => {
  // Here's when I gather the information that I need
  dispatchGetUserEvents(element.user, response => {
    userParties.push(response);
    console.log('dispatchGetUserEvents', userParties); // Here the array is full of elements, like it's supposed to be
  });
});

console.log('outside', userParties); // However, here 'userParties' return '[]'
this.setState({ followUsersEvents: userParties });
this.setState({ userImage: userImg });
```

run this code and you will see that `outside` will be printed first and `dispatchGetUserEvents` later, as I mentioned in comments `dispatchGetUserEvents` is async function, so first will be executed `console.log('outside', ...);`

Comment: Thta's correct, the first thing that prints it's the 'outside', and then 'dispatchGetUserEvents'. So, how can I tackle this issue?